# DNS Slave server default limits on transfers?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-hosting, named-conf

We have a slave dns server that has been working fine for 2 years.  Today we got reached over 100 zones and the slave gives us this error message on the last 2 domains

```
Sep 15 20:27:19 ns1 named[992]: zone my.domain.com/IN: refresh: skipping zone transfer as master xx.xx.x.xx#53 (source 0.0.0.0#0) is unreachable (cached)
```

Does Named have some limits in place that we need to increase?

I did try adding:

transfers-out 200;
transfers-in 200;

To both the slave and the master and restarted named on both machines with no luck.

Any one know what the issue is?

Comment: Is the Master server reachable from the Slave via port 53?

Comment: Does a manual `dig axfr` from the slave get a successful transfer of that specific domain?

Comment: Anything relevant in the log file on the master? You may need to look back in the log a bit since the slave caches the fact that a transfer failed and doesn't retry for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Just seeing I never added the proper fix here...rather simple once it came down to it.  Someone had added new firewall rules, and one of those blocked port 53.  So the server could not receive any records through port 53.